# Printing a groupby object's content

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a table like

```
fruit       day
---------------------
apple       Mon
apple       Mon
apple       Tue
banana      Tue
```

I want to group by on fruit and have the unique days in a list and another column for the len of the list. I'm familiar with how to do groupby but not sure how to get those unique values in a list and get it's length. 
Looking for a result like

```
fruit     day_list    count
apple     [Mon, Tue]  2 
banana    [Tue]       1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with `groupby` and `unique` + `nunique`

```
df.groupby('fruit').day.agg(['unique','nunique']).reset_index()
Out[242]: 
    fruit      unique  nunique
0   apple  [Mon, Tue]        2
1  banana        [Tu]        1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do two aggerations on day column (unique for unique values and nunique for number on unique values).

```
df.groupby('fruit')['day'].agg(['unique', 'nunique'])

Output:
            unique  nunique
fruit                      
apple   [Mon, Tue]        2
banana       [Tue]        1
```

Comment: What is the different between yours and mine?

Comment: @Wen-Ben Oh I'm sorry, I not notice that an answer had been posted while I was still working on mine (I'm pretty new to Pandas so I had to test it out before posting and that took a second.)